# Rename string if two columns are identical

Tags: r, dplyr, duplicates

I have a table with several columns. I want to number a string in a column in case this is identical. --> want to go to wide format later this is why I cannot have identical strings.

Example:

```
Name    drink   number
stefan  beer    3
stefan beer 4
stefan wine 4
michael soda 2
```

should be

```
Name    drink   number
stefan  beer_1  3
stefan beer_2   4
stefan wine 4
michael soda 2
```

Right now I only remove the columns but would be great just to add a number to the second column.

```
df[!duplicated(df[c(1,2)]),]
```

Thank you so much for your help. i guess this can be done with replace as well as with dplyr package and mutate but not sure how the code has to look like.

Thanks.
 Dennis

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is `make.unique`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
   mutate(drink = make.unique(drink, sep = "_"))
```

Comment: does it have to be grouped? should work as well without?

Comment: @Dennis I had the same doubt.  In the OP's code, it is doing for both columns, but description is for a single column.  If it should be for both columns, then the first one should also be changed.  I am not sure

Comment: getting this error from 'mutate' Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: 'names' must be a character vector.

Comment: @Dennis you need first to  make sure your `df$drink` is not a factor. E.g `df$drink <- as.character(df$drink)`

Comment: that did the job.  one questions ( will tick as solve) why do we need group_by before and why does this take into account for the mutate make.unique then? thanks!!

Comment: Didn't know about `make.unique`! Was working on a different approach and I don't get why this works `df %>%
  group_by(Name, drink) %>%
  mutate(rows = n(),
         drink_upd = ifelse(rows > 1, paste0(drink,"_",row_number()), drink)) %>%
  ungroup()` but this doesn't `df %>%
  group_by(Name, drink) %>%
  mutate(drink_upd = ifelse(n() > 1, paste0(drink,"_",row_number()), drink)) %>%
  ungroup()`

Comment: @akrun, 1 more thing when I run the code it gives me `beer` and then `beer_1` seems it is not starting from `1`, could you please help here sir?

Comment: @Dennis  as @lebatsnok mentioned, you need a character vector based on `?make.names` `names - a character vector`.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I was initially thinking about going exactly like the OP's expected output with some `if else`.  But the end goal seems to be some identification for those duplicated elements.  Here, `make.unique` starts the numbering from the duplicate elements without including the first one.